# Customize Kendo DataSource's OData URL?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, odata, kendo-datasource

I'm using a Kendo Grid pointed to an ASP.NET Web API OData controller. I'm wondering if it's possible to customize/overwrite the generated OData URL that Kendo's DataSource generates? My issue is my date fields are DateTimeOffset and I'm trying to sort by those fields, however Kendo's model fields only support string/bool/number/date, nothing for DateTimeOffset. The URL it generates for date fields is:

http://localhost/api/odata/customers?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=10&%24filter=(CreatedDate+ge+datetime%272015-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%27) which fails.

It should be:

http://localhost:900/api/odata/customers?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=10&%24filter=(CreatedDate+ge+**datetimeoffset**%272015-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%27)

Is it possible to force it to use datetimeoffset instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using the right "odata" transport. Try with "odata-v4". More info is available [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-type).

Answer (score 0):

For my ASP.NET Web API 2's [OData V4](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part2-url-conventions.html) controllers, I actually need this URL format:

`http://localhost:XX/odata/Things?$filter=DteTmOfsField eq 2012-12-03T07:16:23Z`

And this javascript is working pretty good for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata-v4",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/odata/Things/",
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options,type) {
                        var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(options, type);

                        if (paramMap.$filter) {

                            paramMap.$filter = paramMap.$filter.replace(/datetime'([-0-9T:]{19})'/gi, "$1Z");

                        }
                        paramMap.$count = true;
                        delete paramMap.$inlinecount; // <-- remove inlinecount parameter
                        delete paramMap.$format; // <-- remove format parameter

                        return paramMap;
                    }
                },
```

Comment: As far as a more specific answer to the O.P.'s desired URL format, I think this change to my above javascript would get you there:
`paramMap.$filter = paramMap.$filter.replace(/datetime'([-0-9T:]{19})'/gi, "datetimeoffset'$1'");`